# Какую библиотеку лучше использовать при создании графиков android java?

Tags: android, график, поиск-библиотек

Какую библиотеку лучше использовать при создании графиков подобного плана?

[image: пример]

[image: пример]

Comment: многие используют webviev

Comment: рисовать простейшие графики? легче самому написать свой View

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Присмотритесь к этим библиотекам

https://github.com/wordplat/ikvStockChart

https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart

https://github.com/ddanny/achartengine

https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android

https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot

https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView